# Js и ResponseText

Tags: ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте,помогите разобраться, отправляю ajax запрос,получаю ответ:

var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseText; 
   console.log(xmlResponse);//возвращает много html кода

но как с этим полученным кодом работать?например console.log(xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName('small')); ничего не возвращает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Превратите его в DOM

```
var mydoc=document.createElement('div');
    mydoc.innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    console.log(mydoc.getElementsByTagName('small'));
```

так-же можно responseType сделать, но в IE это поддерживается только с 10го.